# How to get data in pandas dataframe in a range of date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a front end where my clients select a date period like 
date_start = 2020/01/03 
date_end = 2020/03/10

I have a data frame that has 1975 lines and 4 columns, including Date, like:

Date|Tax|Values|Total

I need to get all columns in that to be in a period between date_start and date_end on Pandas Dataframe. How Can I get it?

What I tried:

Try to do it with code:

```
new_df= df[(df['Date'] >= date_start) & (df['Date'] <= date_end)]
```

But the return was wrong.

Comment: Make sure your `Date` column and `date_start` and `date_end` are converted to the `Timestamp` data type. Then `df[df['Date'].between(date_start, date_end)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome.

Keep in mind you're not filtering for those dates but selecting the dates in between.

Try the following:

```
# To make sure your column is in datetime format
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])  

new_df = df.loc[(df['Date']>=date_start) & (df['Date']<=date_end)]
```

Comment: I used this way, but, the return that I had received was:

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Data, Cota, PL]
Index: []

I validated my file and had information in range of dates selected...

Comment: Did yoh make sure that date-star and date_end are also datetime?

Comment: Yes, I made de parser.

Comment: Hm odd, try posting a sample of your data and the results

Comment: Print of dataframe:

0      2012-03-07
1      2012-03-08
2      2012-03-09
3      2012-03-12
4      2012-03-13
          ...
1969   2020-01-0
1970   2020-01-09
1971   2020-01-10

Print date_start and date_end:
2019-04-01
2019-02-07

Comment: Sorry Gorlomi, I was used the wrong variable...

After adjust it, a new Error was raised...

 raise TypeError(f"Invalid comparison between dtype={left.dtype} and {typ}")
TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and date

Comment: I had um parse in my variables, so the error was showed me. Your answer to be perfectly correct for my problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Make sure to mark the answer as correct so people with the same problen can find it faster

Answer (score 0):

Example:

from_date = "2021-08-27"
to_date = "2021-08-31"

> inclusive can be {“both”, “neither”, “left”, “right”}

```
df[df['date'].between(from_date, to_date, inclusive='both')]
```

This function is equivalent to:

```
 df[(from_date <= df['date']) & (df['date'] <= to_date)]
```